# Rails render method takes content: argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The render method in Rails has a lot of defaults and I can't find a unified documentation.

Why does this:

```
render 'modal_new', content: @content
```

Work? I can't find where content: is a valid argument name. I believe the effect is something like locals: {content: @content}. But not sure how!

Comment: what is `modal_new`? And where do you call this render, from a view?

Comment: _modal_new.html.erb is a partial, and yes from a view...

Comment: In this case, yes, it's the same as `render partial: 'modal_new', locals: { content: @content }`.

Comment: You can find shorthands in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html, 'Rendering the default case' chapter

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Vasilisa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

I may be oversimplifying things, but here's how I've seen it mostly done.

In a controller, you typically can skip the render call if your view name matches your action/method of the same controller.  However, you would need to make an explicit render call when your controller doesn't match.   example:

```
class ContentController < ApplicationController
  # no render needed, as the view will be `new`
  def new
    @content = Content.new
  end 

  def create
    @content = Content.new(params)
    if(@content.save)
      redirect_to @content
    else
      # because there's an error, I want to render 'new' for the user to re-enter data
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

In a view, you would typically call render to incorporate partials.  For instance, you might share the form fields between your `new` and `edit` views as such:

```
<h1>New Content</h1>
<%= render 'form', content: @content %>
<%= link_to 'back', contents_path %>
```

In this case, `'form'` references the partial `app/views/content/_form.html.erb` and passes in the locals `content: @content`

Hopefully this is all helpful.